# Symfony2 export db to doctrine fixtures

Tags: doctrine, symfony, fixtures

Is there any way to export my existing database rows as doctrine fixtures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately not, there is currently not an export function as there was in symfony 1.x

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [DoctrineFixturesGeneratorBundle](https://github.com/Webonaute/DoctrineFixturesGeneratorBundle) in order to export the data from database as fixtures:

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:fixture --entity=Blog:BlogPost \
--ids="12 534 124" --name="bug43" --order="1"
```